# Is it possible to desaturate a ggplot easily?

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, markdown

Is it possible to desaturate a `ggplot` easily?

---

In principle, there could be two possible strategies.
First, apply some function to a `ggplot` object (or, possibly, `Grob` object) to desaturate all colors. Second, some trick to print `ggplot` desaturated while rendering a `.rmd` file. Both strategies would be ok for me, but first one is, of course, more promissing.
Creating `ggplot` in greys from the beginning is not a good option as the idea is to have the same plot as if it was printed in shades of grey.

---

There were some similar questions and remarkably good answers on how to perform desaturation in R. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314701/r-reducing-colour-saturation-of-a-colour-palette/26322593#26322593) is a convenient way to desaturate color palette. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31800687/how-to-get-a-pixel-matrix-from-grayscale-image-in-r/31804561#31804561) is the way of desaturating a raster image. What I'm looking for, is a simple way of desaturating the whole `ggplot`.

Comment: Can you export the plot to PNG at high DPI, load the PNG via raster and desaturate that via the solution you link to?  That seems like a low-cost solution if all you're trying to do is test what it would look like.

Comment: I hope, there is a simple way of desaturating the ggplot object itself. Turning vector graphics to raster in R doesn't feel right.

Comment: Well, if it's just that you want to keep it in vector format you could export the `ggplot` output to a PDF device with `colormodel="gray"`, that might get the results you're looking for?

Comment: Cool! I didn't know about `colormodel="gray"` option. Is there something similar when you render a plot in `knirt`?

Comment: I'm with @ikashnitsky, desaturating the ggplot object itself is useful. For example, it allows you to make a side-by-side plot of the original plot and the desaturated plot, straight from R, without having to write the plot to a file and reading it back in. It's really useful if you want to write R Markdown documents about the effects of desaturation and colorblindness.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just came across this question. The experimental package colorblindr (written by Claire McWhite and myself) contains a function that can do this in a generic way. I'm using the example figure from @hrbrmstr:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)

gg <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=mpg, y=wt, fill=factor(cyl), size=factor(carb)), 
             color="black", shape=21) + 
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18)) +
  facet_wrap(~am)
gg
```

[image]

Now let's desaturate this plot, using the `edit_colors()` function from colorblindr:

```
library(colorblindr) # devtools::install_github("clauswilke/colorblindr")
library(colorspace) # install.packages("colorspace", repos = "http://R-Forge.R-project.org") --- colorblindr requires the development version
# need also install cowplot; current version on CRAN is fine.

gg_des <- edit_colors(gg, desaturate)
cowplot::ggdraw(gg_des)
```

[image]

The function `edit_colors()` takes a ggplot2 object or grob and applies a color transformation function (here `desaturate`) to all colors in the grob.

We can provide additional arguments to the transformation function, e.g. to do partial desaturation:

```
gg_des <- edit_colors(gg, desaturate, amount = 0.7)
cowplot::ggdraw(gg_des)
```

[image]

We can also do other transformations, e.g. color-blind simulations:

```
gg_des <- edit_colors(gg, deutan)
cowplot::ggdraw(gg_des)
```

[image]

Finally, we can manipulate line colors and fill colors separately. E.g., we could make all filled areas blue. (Not sure this is useful, but whatever.)

```
gg_des <- edit_colors(gg, fillfun = function(x) "lightblue")
cowplot::ggdraw(gg_des)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As per my comment above, this might be the quickest/dirtiest way to achieve the desaturation for a `ggplot2` object:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
p <- qplot(rnorm(50), rnorm(50), col="Class")
print(p)
```

[image]

```
pdf(file="p.pdf", colormodel="grey")
  print(p)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I tried this with the new viridis color palette since it desaturates well (i.e. it should be noticeable between the colored & non-colored plots):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(colorspace)
library(viridis) # devtools::install_github("sjmgarnier/viridis") for scale_fill_viridis

gg <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=mpg, y=wt, fill=factor(cyl), size=factor(carb)), 
             color="black", shape=21) + 
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18)) +
  facet_wrap(~am)

gb <- ggplot_build(gg)
gb$data[[1]]$colour <- desaturate(gb$data[[1]]$colour)
gb$data[[1]]$fill <- desaturate(gb$data[[1]]$fill)

gt <- ggplot_gtable(gb)

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gt)
```

You end up having to manipulate on the grob level.

Here's the plot pre-desaturate:

[image]

and here's the plot post-desature:

[image]

<strike>I'm trying to figure out why the legend got skipped and this may miss other highly customized ggplot aesthetics & components, so even while it's not a complete answer, perhaps it might be useful (and perhaps someone else can tack on to it or expand on it in another answer). It should just be a matter of replacing the right bits in either the `gb` object or `gt` object.</strike>

**UPDATE** I managed to find the right grob element for the legend:

```
gt$grobs[[12]][[1]][["99_9c27fc5147adbe9a3bdf887b25d29587"]]$grobs[[4]]$gp$fill <- 
    desaturate(gt$grobs[[12]][[1]][["99_9c27fc5147adbe9a3bdf887b25d29587"]]$grobs[[4]]$gp$fill)
gt$grobs[[12]][[1]][["99_9c27fc5147adbe9a3bdf887b25d29587"]]$grobs[[6]]$gp$fill <- 
    desaturate(gt$grobs[[12]][[1]][["99_9c27fc5147adbe9a3bdf887b25d29587"]]$grobs[[6]]$gp$fill)
gt$grobs[[12]][[1]][["99_9c27fc5147adbe9a3bdf887b25d29587"]]$grobs[[8]]$gp$fill <- 
    desaturate(gt$grobs[[12]][[1]][["99_9c27fc5147adbe9a3bdf887b25d29587"]]$grobs[[8]]$gp$fill)

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

The machinations to find the other `gp` elements that need desaturation aren't too bad either.

Comment: Thanks! That's really great! Your solution could be easily warped in a handy function. 
Yes, very strange behavior of legend labels. I cannot locate where the problem is.

Comment: I managed to figure out the grobs for them. You just need to (carefully) walk the `gt$grobs` tree and `desaturate()` all of the `gp` `fill` and `color` elements (some won't exists).

Comment: And thanks a lot for `viridis` palette. It's magnificent! Do I get it right that it is not only print-friendly but also colorblind-friendly?

Comment: Aye. I have some extended viridis examples [here](https://rud.is/b/2015/07/20/using-the-new-viridis-colormap-in-r-thanks-to-simon-garnier/). It's not perfect for discrete situations but it works well and is color-blind, print and far more "normal" linear precise than anything else to-date (perhaps parula comes close, but it's proprietary).

Comment: @ hrbrmstr  Is there any way of anchoring `midpoint` with `viridis`? I mean like in `scale_fill_gradient2`.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of (at least with the current state of the way the base palette was generated by the vis researchers). I'll have a look at the python code, though, and see if it's possible.

Comment: A few months back I wrote a function that does exactly what @hrbrmstr suggests: "(carefully) walk the `gt$grobs` tree and `desaturate()` all of the `gp` `fill` and `color` elements." (In the most general case, though, you also need to cover raster grobs, which are a bit more tricky.) See the answer I posted.